# create office files from python

Tags: python, excel, ms-word, report

We have a project in python with django.
We need to generate **complex** word, excel and pdf files.

For the rest of our projects which were done in PHP we used [PHPexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) , 
[PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com)  and tcpdf for PDF.

What libraries for python would you recommend for creating this kind of files ? (for excel and word its imortant to use the open xml file format xlsx , docx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python-docx may help ( https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx ).

Python doesn't have highly-developed tools to manipulate word documents. I've found the java library xdocreport ( https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/ ) to be the best by far for Word reporting. Because I need to generate PCL, which is efficiently done via FOP I also use docx4j.

To integrate this with my python, I use the spark framework to wrap it up with a simple web service, and use `requests` on the python side to talk to the service.

Comment: Python-docx lacks a lot of features compared to PHPword. like custom headers and footers and I did not find any good docuemtnation for it.

Comment: @Revelation It's simple to work with (the examples are good), but quite limited. That's why I recommend a java solution. If you're insisted, I'm willing to licence the code I already have, for not very much (does word reporting, you could integrate other functionality).

Comment: Do you think its ok to create the file with php / java libraries and pass the data as argument in xml/json format ? Using a service for this seems overkill.

Comment: @Revelation I think it's fine to create it however you like, and interface to that other code however you like. Creating a webservice can be very, very simple. In my case, I just send it a multipart post request, and the requested document is returned as the body. I think you will find that any other form of IPC is more work, but use whatever works for you.

Comment: @Revelation Incidentally, I'm totally serious about licensing. Get in touch if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

For excel, there's [openpyxl](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/), which actually is a python port of PHPexcel, afaik. I haven't used it yet, but it sounds ok to me.

Comment: We already found that, but it lacks a lot of features from the original PHPexcel

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/). It takes reStructuredText files and converts them to a range of output files. Included in the package are HTML, LaTeX and .odf file writers but in the [sandbox](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/sandbox/) there are a whole load of other writers for writing to other formats, see for example, the [WordML](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/sandbox/rst2wordml/) writer *(disclaimer: I haven't used it)*.

The advantage of this solution is that you can write plain text (reStructuredText) master files, which are human readable as is, and then convert to a range of other file formats as required.

Whilst not a Python solution, you should also look at [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) a Haskell library which supports a *much* wider range of output and input formats than docutils. One major advantage of Pandoc over Docutils is that you can do the reverse translation, i.e. WordML to reStructuredText. You can try Pandoc [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try).

Answer (score 0):

I have never used any libraries for this, but you can change the extension of any `docx`, `xlsx` file to `zip`, and see the magic!

Generating openxml files is as simple as generating couple of XML files (you can use templates) and zipping it.

Comment: I know that, but we need to generate complex documents so this is out of question. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to generate PDF is to generate HTML (with CSS+images) and convert it using `wkhtmltopdf` tool.

Comment: for pdf files we found a lot o libraries which are ok. we need more help with the office files..